# Why required "=" before ANY function with array as param, in postgres procedure?

Tags: arrays, postgresql, stored-procedures, any

I was answering a postgres question yesterday, and also came across a postgres thread ([here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/758d5e7f0802271634q7d8bbdc0t29cb94e932526f22@mail.gmail.com)) where they describe the following error:

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = text[]
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The error seems to appear whenever an ARRAY string type is fed to `ANY` without using `= ANY`. This seems completely strange since based on language, logic, and sql conventions, usually you have (e.g. `IN`):

**`variable FUNCTION(set)`**

instead of.

**`variable = FUNCTION(set)`** , **unless ofcourse operator is a summation/count operation returning one result :)**

It would make more senseto have `variable ANY(Set/Array)` instead of `variable=ANY(Set/Array)`. Similar example is the `IN` function.

Can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: Which is really interesting is that the linked query (`select 'x' = ANY ('{x,y,z}'::text[])`) should work IMHO. Because `ANY()` actually has 2 formats: `ANY (<array-value>)` and `ANY (<sub-query>)`. With the latter, all selected values are accumulated into an array, just like with the `ARRAY(<sub-query>)` constructor (i.e. `SELECT 'x'::text = ANY (SELECT 'x'::text)` works). Also, ANY works with multidimensional arrays too (i.e. `SELECT 'x'::text = ANY ('{{x,y,z}}'::text[])` works)...

Comment: ...  Therefore both `SELECT 'x'::text = ANY (ARRAY(SELECT 'x'::text))` and `SELECT 'x'::text = ANY (ARRAY(SELECT '{x,y,z}'::text[]))` work too, which suggests that the original query should work too. This may actually be a bug in query parser and/or the type system.

Comment: @pozs Though I saw in the documentation the proper format is `variable operator ANY(set)`... where `operator` can be anything like `=` or `>` that is applied to the set.

Comment: yes, unfortunately the docs here are not as clear as at other places. It doesn't mention the sub-select form (however it's an ANSI SQL requirement), neither the multidimensional array support (I didn't know it either until now). Instead it uses the blurry "array expression" terminology to cover these 2 cases. I suspect that this "bug" may came in with 9.5, where the new [constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) syntax finally allowed the multidimensional array creation (OFC only when the result is rectangular)

Comment: My point is, syntax-wise, there should be no distinction between `<expr> <operator> ANY (<sub-select>)` and `<expr> <operator> ANY (ARRAY(<sub-select>))`, because they mean the same thing. But the latter can run without any trouble, but the former gives error, like: "operator not found <type> <operator> <type>[]"

Comment: @pozs you are right... weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IN (...)` is basically equivalent to `= ANY (ARRAY[...])`

Crucially, *`ANY` is not a function*. It's syntax defined by the SQL standard, and is no more a function than `GROUP BY` or the `OVER` clause in a window function.

The reason that `=` is required before `ANY` is that `ANY` can apply to other operators too. What it means is "Test the operator to the left against every element in the array on the right, and return true if the test is true for at least one element."

You can use `> ANY (ARRAY[...])` or whatever. It's a general purpose operator that isn't restricted to `=`. Notably useful for `LIKE ANY` (albeit with somewhat bad performance).

There is `ALL` too, which does much the same thing but returns true only if all results are true.

Comment: Yes..I just realized this by re-reading the documentation. `expression operator ANY (array expression)`. `The left-hand expression is evaluated and compared to each element of the array using the given operator` ... not readily obvious but I didn't RTFM :S . https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-comparisons.html#AEN17438 . I guess it's a common mistake.